# Install Ambari based on docker on multiple hosts

Tags: docker, ambari

I have three servers and I want to set up Ambari. Unfortunately I have CentOS7 which currently isn't supported by Ambari. So I decided to use docker to overcome the OS dependency. I have found various docker-based Ambari version like [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Development+in+Docker) and [this](http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/12/04/multinode-ambari-1-7-0/). The second one seems to be really good and easy to install on one host creating a pseudo-cluster, but I failed to install it on different hosts. I followed the described steps one by one trying to adjust them to the fact that I am not one the same host but when I try to assign a new host I get an error that the hostname is not valid.

For the first solution on the other hand, I can't understand the following. How can I make the containers on each host be aware of each other? Because Ambari needs every host to can ssh each other without password.

Excuse me in advance for my lack of expertise in this domain. Any comment would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambari 2.2+ can be installed successfully and works fine on CentOS 7. Then you can install HDP 2.0+.
The links in your question try to install 1.6 and 1.7.